# Is there a recommended max size limit for docker images as good practice?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-image

I am using a Google model (3.6GB) in my docker image which makes its size around 5GB. Everything works fine for me.

**However,** I am just wondering if there are any limits on the docker image size or any recommendations in this regard which should be followed as a good practice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After searching blogs and codes, I am nearly sure that `Default Base Size` is 100GB. So, you can use within this limit. I have collected a code snippet from [moby/moby](https://github.com/moby/moby/blob/master/daemon/graphdriver/devmapper/deviceset.go#L38).

```
defaultDataLoopbackSize      int64  = 100 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024
defaultMetaDataLoopbackSize  int64  = 2 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024
defaultBaseFsSize            uint64 = 10 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024
defaultThinpBlockSize        uint32 = 128 // 64K = 128 512b sectors
```

Previously, the size was `10GB`. See the [Pull Request](https://github.com/moby/moby/pull/14709).

Also, You can increase the size. You may review the [Device Mapper Driver](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/storagedriver/device-mapper-driver) docs for details.

Comment: As of today (7/22/2018) it's [set to 300gb](https://github.com/moby/moby/blob/3a633a712c8bbb863fe7e57ec132dd87a9c4eff7/daemon/graphdriver/devmapper/devmapper_test.go#L23)